# Question about interpretting an interaction term in a regression

Tags: regression, interaction, econometrics, interpretation

If I run the regression:

$y = \beta_o + \beta_1 * Black  + \beta_2 Black*X + \eta$

where Black = 1 if the individual is black, and x is a continuous variable, and I am omitting x separately as a regressor, and $\eta$ is the error term. What exactly is the interpretation of $\beta_2$?

The way I see it there are two different ways to look at it:

1. $\frac{dE[y|x,black=1]}{dx}$ = $\beta_2$

which is then the marginal effect of x on y for blacks, but also:

2. Taking mean differnces: $E[y|x,black=1]-E[y|x,black=0]$ = $\beta_1 + \beta_2 x$,
   and then:

$\frac{d(E[y|x,black=1]-E[y|x,black=0])}{dx}$  = $\beta_2$

, which is now saying the mean difference between black and non black is changing with x. These seem like quite different interpretations. Is one of these logically incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the model you have set up none of them are logically incorrect.

The model $$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Black + \beta_2 X\cdot Black + u,$$ has what I will call a weird restriction

$$\mathbb E[y\lvert x , black=0] = \mathbb E[y \lvert black=0] = \beta_0.$$

The restrictions says that while for black individuals $X$ is important for the outcome variable $Y$ this is not the case for non-black individuals. If you really could come up with such a variable - and I am not arguing it is impossible - then it should come to you as no surprise that

$$(1) \ \frac{\partial \mathbb E[Y \lvert black=1, x]}{\partial x} = \beta_2$$
and

$$(2) \ \frac{\partial (\mathbb E[Y \lvert black=1, x] - \mathbb E[Y \lvert black=0, x]}{\partial x} = \beta_2$$

If however, you really believe that (1) and (2) should not be the same - you say they express different things - then you should simply use a more flexible model

$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Black + \beta_2 X\cdot Black + \beta_3 X + u$$

for which
$$(1) \ \frac{\partial \mathbb E[Y \lvert black=1, x]}{\partial x} = \beta_2 + \beta_3$$
and

$$(2) \ \frac{\partial (\mathbb E[Y \lvert black=1, x] - \mathbb E[Y \lvert black=0, x]}{\partial x} = (\beta_2 + \beta_3) - \beta_3 = \beta_2$$

In any case the more flexible model is probably preferred because it allows you to test whether the "weird" restriction is "true".

Comment: Well described. Here's a different wording: $\beta_2$ here is just like any parameter, because there is no "real" interaction between the dummy and regressor: $X$ is never observed for non-black. So it is sort of an "artificial" interaction term (what @Jesper calls "weird"), since we don't know if the dummy actually affects (interacts with) $X$ or not. So $\beta_2$ is simply the amount that $X$ influences $y$ by for blacks only.

Comment: Yes, agree that is also a nice way to put it.